# error when declaring an inner class template field

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an error with the following code, using the inner template class Node.
the error is when declaring the root private field:

"member **root** declared as a template".

```
template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
class TreapBST : public AbstractBST<KeyType, ValueType>
{
public:
    .....

private:
   template <typename K, typename V>
   struct Node
   {
       ....
   };

    template <typename K, typename V>
    typename TreapBST<K, V>::Node<K, V>* root = nullptr;

};
```

Comment: And what should `template ... root` mean? How are you going to specify its template arguments? Or how should a compiler deduce them?

Comment: it should be a pointer to the root of the Treap (BST + Heap)

Comment: But what are `K` and `V` that a compiler should use?

Comment: You cannot have template fields or field templates. Luckily you don't need any in this case. You want `Node * root = nullptr;`. `struct Node` shouldn't be a template either.

Comment: I removed the duplicate here. There are other stuff than simply adding `template` at the right spot.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. 
but it doesn't work without struct Node being a template

Comment: in what way does it not work? Node will be a template in the sense that it is a private class of a class template. When you write a class template you do not need to keep repeating `template <typename K, typename V>` unless you want that K and V to be *two different types* than the class parameters KeyType and ValueType

Comment: Ah i see, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the basic idea right but are getting the syntax confused.

When you write a class template you do not need to keep repeating `template <typename K, typename V>` for each member unless you want that `K` and `V` to be two types that are different from class parameters `KeyType` and `ValueType`. If you just need `KeyType` and `ValueType` you don't need to redeclare members as templates.

For example the following will compile:

```
template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
class AbstractBST
{
    //...
};

template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
class TreapBST : public AbstractBST<KeyType, ValueType>
{
public:
    //...

private:

    struct Node
    {
        KeyType key;
        ValueType val;
        //...
    };

    Node* root = nullptr;

};

int main()
{
    TreapBST<std::string, int> treap;
    return 0;
};
```